# Why jQuery is not a W3C standard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, standards, w3c

I've read and heard that jQuery is ***not*** a W3C standard but at the same time I couldn't find the reason why it is so.  Any explanation with reasoning are appreciated.

**EDIT:** OK, may be I should reword/rephrase my original question.  Actually, the question I had in my mind was -- `Does jQuery follow W3C standards?` but while posting it just got reworded.

Comment: jquery team !== w3c working group - and jQuery is *"only"* a library built over a standard language (ECMA-262)

Comment: Based on the FAQ, I don't think this question belongs on SO.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Why would jQuery be a standard?  jQuery is just a (rather popular) library.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for the programmers.stackexchange.com site. Good question, but not something that is discussed on SO

Comment: @elevine: FYI.  Rephrased the question.

Comment: Do re-consider *downvote* and *closed* status of this question. Please refer the **EDIT** section in this question.

Comment: @Gnanam: That makes even less sense.  There are no standards for jQuery to follow.

Comment: I really found this question useful and was searching for the same. I am really dissapointed to see that some 'too-clever' moderator has halted the responses on this question. I dont know where do these ppl come, who dont even have common sense of what should be blocked and what not! Alas ....

Answer (score 22):

There are already W3 standards for selecting and manipulating elements, jQuery is just a library that facilitates that. In other words, it is possible to do everything jQuery can do with regular JavaScript, so there is no reason to make it any kind of standard.

As to the edited version "does jQuery follow W3C standards", the answer is no. It uses non-standard properties and methods like innerHTML, as well as some browser-specific properties. Though it does this in a way that is useful and creates an "abstraction layer" that helps developers access these properties easily without worrying as much about browser compatibility, jQuery still does go against certain standards.